# Can not update electron application

Tags: electron

Does anybody hit this error while updating autoupdate for electron application.
It says:
Error: Can not find Squirrel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCiSx.png)

below is my code:

```js
const server = 'http://10.172.120.67:8081'
// const url = `${server}/update/${process.platform}/${app.getVersion()}`
const url = `${server}/update/`
console.log(url)
autoUpdater.setFeedURL({ url })
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (event, releaseNotes, releaseName) => {
  console.log("getin")
  const dialogOpts = {
    type: 'info',
    buttons: ['Restart', 'Later'],
    title: 'Application Update',
    message: process.platform === 'win32' ? releaseNotes : releaseName,
    detail: 'A new version has been downloaded. Restart the application to apply the updates.'
  }

  dialog.showMessageBox(dialogOpts).then((returnValue) => {
    if (returnValue.response === 0) autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()
  })
})

autoUpdater.on('error', message => {
  console.error('There was a problem updating the application')
  console.error(message)
})

autoUpdater.on('update-avliable', function (info){
  console.log('update-avliable')
})

autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', function () {
  console.log('checking-for-update')
});

console.log("hello electron")

autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
```

Comment: Post the error message as text/code instead of image so then google and other indexers and search engines can find it

Answer (score -1):

Try calling the check for updates when the app is ready:

```
app.on('ready', function() {
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
}
```